How to pass Jupyter Lab password in the command line?
I have set a password for jupyter lab such that every time I start and open it in the browser, it asks for a password before loading the interface. I used jupyter lab password, and my hashed password is written to ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json like below:
{
  "IdentityProvider": {
    "hashed_password": "my_hashed_password"
  }
}

I am now trying to write a service to start jupyter lab automatically on boot and auto enter my password in the ExecStart line. What is the command line argument or configuration file option that achieves this?
In this guide, the author mentioned a configuration I can use to auto enter the password.
However, in my jupyter_lab_config.py, all options related to password or token are marked as deprecated, like the one below. Instead, how can I use the PasswordIdentityProvider to auto enter the password? There is little information I can find.
## DEPRECATED in 2.0. Use PasswordIdentityProvider.hashed_password
#  Default: ''
# c.ServerApp.password = ''

